# How to get the value of a selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to get the selected username from a RadGrid called `GridView`, the username is a column on the RadGrid called `UserName`.

I have tried:

```
GridDataItem item =(GridDataItem)GridView.MasterTableView.Items[GridView.SelectedItems[0].ItemIndex];
string lblOrdHeadName = item["UserName"].Text;
```

But this throws an error on the fist line that says:

'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Does anyone know what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
    List<GridDataItem> Items = (from item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Cast<GridDataItem>()
                                where item.Selected
                                select item).ToList();

    if (Items != null && Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem item in Items)
        {
            string strUsername = item["UserName"].Text;
        }
    }
```